# React Navigation Animated Header in Mobile

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-animated

I've a layout having a `Header` (React navigation) which is transparent and a `ScrollView` which contains a banner and other items. What I want to achieve is:

**FIRST)** To animate the header color on scroll i.e. Transparency decreases. Also note that I need to animate the `StatusBar` color along.

**SECONDLY)** To interchange the items in Header using their opacities i.e. one item hides and other one shows up. Plus, I want to hide another item in the banner (in ScrollView)

I'm attaching some images for expected result. Hope it will help understand my requirement easily.

[image] [image] [image] [image]

a) There is a logo in header. b) When scroll starts, at specific point, logo disappears and search bar starts appearing in header and disappearing from banner, also header & statusbar colors alpha starts increasing. c) Animation completed. d) End result.

I've almost succeeded with the help of [this tutorial](https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e).

[image] .

But its not working with Android statusbar. Also it doesn't have interchanging items in header. And it is not using React navigation header but custom header.

Comment: hi i am facing same issue with statusbar..